# Multiple HBM files with multiple classes for the same table

Tags: java, hibernate

Can you have 1 table be referred to by 2 different HBM's mapped to 2 different classes (they are unrelated, basic classes, no inheritance).

I know it may be bad practice because of duplication but it has to do with code maintenance. I'm trying to avoid removing one of the classes.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can you have 1 table be referred to by 2 different HBM's mapped to 2 different classes (they are unrelated, basic classes, no inheritance).

Yes you can. Just make sure to include stuff for optimistic locking if you are using optimistic locking.